# Run a php script based on the current input ID using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i get the current product code ID to be added to the current row "imgsample" cell?

An example can be found here:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/bpApd/3/

```
var counter = 0;
    //Order Form
    $("#add").click(function() {
        counter++;
        var cln = $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last').clone(true);
        cln.find("[id^='prodcode'], [id^='meterage']").each(function(i, val) {
            val.id = val.id.match(/^([^0-9]+)[0-9]*$/)[1] + "" + counter;
        });
        cln.insertAfter('#ordertable tbody>tr:last');
        $('#ordertable tbody>tr:last input').val('');
        $('td.imgsample:last a').remove();
        return false;
    });

$("#prodcode").blur(function() {
$.post(
         'public/themes/lbd/js/searchimage.php', //this page reads the image code and gives you the image location
         { action: 'searchimage', imgreference: $(this).val() },
         function(data) { 
             //export the link as data            
             $("td.imgsample").html(data);
         }
        );
});


<a href="#" id="add">add</a>

<table id="ordertable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>prod:<input type="text" id="prodcode" value="pr-initial" /></td>
            <td>meter:<input type="text" id="meterage" value="mt-initial" /></td>
           <td class="imgsample">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `$('#prodcode').val()` to `$(this).val()` since you are in the context of the `#prodcode` you want (*you are in the `blur` event of it*)

---

**update**

The thing is that since you are deep cloning the table rows you are effectively cloneing the handlers attached. The handlers are already attached to the elements that need them, and you do not need to re-create them to match the new dynamic selector.

This is required only to assign the handler the first time to the first `#prodcode` element.

See the example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/bpApd/1
Add some elements (`with the add button`) and click in them to see what happens..

Comment: Thanks gaby is the $("#prodcode").blur(function() { aspect of the code which changes though...because your clicking in a textbox with #prodcode+id effectively.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Andy see an explanation and an example in the updated answer.

Comment: Thats cool that the id shows...i see what you did there, i must admit im still a little confused how i change mine to run the page with the posted value and update the imgsample.  Sorry :(

Comment: the imgsample is on every row.  I may not have mentioned that.  So the current prodcode needs to update its own unique imgsample on the same row.

Comment: @Andy, i see. You need to use the `.closest('tr')` to go up to the `tr` element and then `.find(td.imgsample)` to go back down to the td you want. look at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/bpApd/4/

Comment: Could i trouble you for one more thing?  I need to get the value of the prodcode box sent to the script which is why i needed the current ID. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Andy look at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bpApd/6 `$(this).val()` will get the value to use in your `.post` and also store the reference to the `.imgsample` so your success callback can find it..

Comment: You are a legend! Working perfectly. Thank you so much for all your help today!